# in android how to clear cache without deleting external databases?

Tags: android

I am developing an app,where i need to clear cache.But whenever  i delete my cache my user data(external database file ) also get erased.i don't want to delete that.

please help me,thanks in advance

this is my code:

```
public void clearApplicationData() 
    {
        File cache = getCacheDir();
        File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());

        if (appDir != null && appDir.isDirectory()) {
              deleteDir(appDir);
           }
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) 
    {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                if(!dir.getAbsolutePath().contains("/data/data/com.example.sounds_english/databases/PhonemeDatabase.db"))
                {
                    boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                    if (!success) {
                    return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();

    }
```

Comment: People will need more context than this to be any help

Comment: Are you clearing cache or clearing data?  http://superuser.com/questions/633960/what-is-app-cache-in-android

Comment: @Pedantic the "clear cache button", clear both cache and data

Comment: how do you addressed external database file? do you use path for you database file?

Comment: @Majid Daei Nejad ----this is the path of my database file /data/data/com.example.sounds_english/databases/PhonemeDatabase.db

Comment: Show your cache clearing code.

Comment: @Rick Falck: this is my code i have added above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you only want to delete the cache, but you are getting the cache directory, backing up to the app's directory, deleting all of the folders in that directory, and then deleting that directory.

Comment: can u suggest me what should i do.I am unable to find out solution for this.any snippet or something with with little more explanation

Comment: What don't you understand, how to use the java File class or how directories work?  Maybe you just need to remove the statement that backs up to the parent directory.